# How can I avoid always having to import my own code in Typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, commonjs

So I was recently hacking on a large Typescript project (https://github.com/BabylonJS/Babylon.js) and I noticed that they don't ever have to import anything, they just use their namespace and the rest is (seemingly) magic.

It got me thinking that I would like to use something similar for myself, so I started a simple typescript project to try it out.

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "outFile": "server.js"
  }
}
```

`src/main.ts`

```
module Test {
  console.log('Main started')
  const server:Server = new Server()
}
```

`src/Server.ts`

```
// import * as http from 'http'

module Test {
  export class Server {
    constructor() {
      console.log('Server initialized')
    }
  }
}
```

If I build this Typescript project then I get output like the following:

```
// import * as http from 'http'
var Test;
(function (Test) {
    var Server = /** @class */ (function () {
        function Server() {
            console.log('Server initialized');
        }
        return Server;
    }());
    Test.Server = Server;
})(Test || (Test = {}));
var Test;
(function (Test) {
    console.log('Main started');
    var server = new Test.Server();
})(Test || (Test = {}));
```

So far, so good. The trouble is that I want to take advantage of some external modules, in this case namely the `http` module, so I uncomment the import line above and now Typescript reports:

`src/server/Server.ts(1,1): error TS6131: Cannot compile modules using option 'outFile' unless the '--module' flag is 'amd' or 'system'.`

Node uses the commonjs module system, so obviously setting either of those flags isn't going to help me much. I have none the less tried them as well as various other combinations of flags, but to no avail. I noticed that BabylonJS doesn't really use external imports like that, opting instead to declare them as external and provide them globally at execution time as script tags. Is there maybe an analogue to that for Node?

Comment: `module` syntax is deprecated, https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html . It's preferable to import things explicitly for numerous reasons. The only apparent benefit of using outFile is that you can skip bundlng, which isn't relevant for Node app because it naturally uses CommonJS modules that don't need to be bundled further.

Comment: Interesting that the compiler doesn't mention that, but it seems like the `namespace` keyword is equivalent and still supported. I'm using `outFile` because otherwise each input typescript files gets translated to an ouput Javascript file and then they have to be all executed or bundled up to work anyway. If there's a build tool that would help support the configuration I'm interested in then I'm open to suggestions!

Comment: *then they have to be all executed or bundled up to work anyway* - that's how it's usually done. You compile them to `dist` folder and execute as regular Node js app. No bundling is needed. You can use ts-node to do this transparently.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I mean they _would have to be further processed to work_. With `outFile` the contents of `Server.ts` is concatenated and runs before the contents of `main.ts` so everything works. With `outDir` there would be separate files and running `main.js` would not be enough.

Comment: It's Node app, isn't it? `import` statements are transpiled to `require`, so running entry point is enough if you state module dependencies explicitly.

Comment: The question was how I could avoid using explicit import statements though...

Comment: You can't and you shouldn't. Omitting explicit dependencies is terrible for project maintenance. Babylon is legacy project and is client-side, so using `module` can be partially justified there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172541/discussion-between-tristan-shelton-and-estus).

Comment: I don't use SO chats because the don't work well with offline. Uncontrollable use of a namespace doesn't benefit a project. You won't ever see this in well-designed modern project. It's bad for same reason the use of globals is bad. You could override namespace variable in another file and never notice this. If the use of imports is a burden to you, I'd suggest to use IDE that does auto-imports. That's a big relief in TS development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me is this:

`Server.ts`

```
declare var http: any;

namespace Test {
  export class Server {
    constructor() {
      console.log('Server initialized')
      const server = http.createServer()
      server.listen()
    }
  }
}
```

Then I simply provide `http` at runtime, for example by prepending a `var http = require('http')` to the output. Thanks to artem for a nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have these two things at the same time, namely

> How can I avoid always having to import my own code in Typescript?

and

> I want to take advantage of some external modules

You can avoid imports only by not using external modules, and the result will be one giant script file that can use external dependencies only as globals created by scripts loaded via `script` tag, as you already noticed.

The language does not allow you to use external modules when you do this. If you have an import of external module at the top level, your file becomes a module and there is no way it could use code from your other files without importing them. And having import of external module inside a namespace is not allowed AFAIK.

That said, I don't think your question - "How can I avoid always having to import my own code in Typescript?" - has a valid premise. CommonJS module system is the solution for preventing large projects from becoming unmaintainable mess. It does not matter if some part of a project is your own code or some external dependency  - if it's a separate part with well-defined interface, it should be packaged and consumed as a module.

Comment: To answer your comment: if my project has very few external dependencies and many pieces of code that are frequently reused across many files (like a `Vector<T>` for example) then it seems sensible to me to put everything in a common namespace with implicit self access. This works fine in C# for example, but I hadn't ever considered using it with Typescript until seeing it in practice.

Comment: There is common namespace in CommonJS, it's called [global object](http://stackabuse.com/using-global-variables-in-node-js/) - you can assign to `global.Vector` for example, and use it as `global.Vector` everywhere, and you can even write ambient type declaration that adds `Vector` to `global`, have it in a separate file and include that file in `tsconfig.json`. That way you could use it in a way similar to C#, but I don't think it's a normal way to do things in node.js.